# How to test that X11Forward is working or not?

Tags: sshd

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

was enabled and sshd reloaded. But how can I test that X Forwarding works or not? xclock is not installed. Perl and python-base is installed, are there any tricks ex.: pop-up a GUI window with Perl? 'echo $DISPLAY' doesn't displays anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I right in assuming that you put the `X11Forwarding yes` in the `sshd` config file on the server? This option just permits forwarding of X11, see `man sshd_config` ([see full man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config)):

```
X11Forwarding
       Specifies whether X11 forwarding is permitted.  The argument must be “yes” or “no”.  The default is “no”.
```

You also need to trigger the client to setup the forwarding, e.g. by calling `ssh -X you@server`.

To verify that X11 forwarding is initiated add another argument `-v` to the ssh call and search for a line like `[...]Requesting X11 forwarding[...]`, e.g.:

```
you@client $ ssh -v -X you@server
[...]
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
[...]
you@server $
```

If it is working properly the `$DISPLAY` variable shouldn't be empty. If it's not set, X11 won't be forwarded.

Answer (score -1):

Install something like system-config-date and then run it.

```
$ yum install system-config-date
$ system-config-date
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because I remember `system-config-date` using a curses-based interface when using SSH without X11 forwarding. Apparently, that behaviour [has since changed](http://serverfault.com/a/305091/190981); also: http://fadvisor.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/timeconfig.png (need to copy the URL and paste into address bar to avoid hot-linking warning). My vote is now locked in but if you edit the question, I can undo the downvote.